# bend not bending

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I've literally been trying to get this to work now for 2 hours. I have been working in 3d (cinema4d and maya) for over 15 years, so I know my way around, but can not get this objec to bend. I've tried bend modifier, curve modifier, followed answer in this support group and looked online. Nothing seems to work. No clue why something that should be so simple need to be so unintuitive and difficult. I figured out the gradient, but man what a task. Why doesn't the gradient texture create a gradient to work with?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/14ooghdtlklphuz/simpleDisplace.blend?dl=0

any advice on how to figure out what should be so basic would be greatly appreciated. It seems that not matter what I start in this application, I can't finish it.

Comment: The attached file does not contain any bend related stuff, it has a displacement modifier, which looks like the order of the modifiers is the wrong way round so you end up with very low res displacement.  Subdivide first, then displacement gives a more defined result.  Also increasing the subdivisions for viewport helps.

Comment: Your question lacks precision (why are you talking about the gradient?), but if you want it to bend, for example to create a pipe, add a Simple Deform modifier and use an empty as "Axis, Origin", then rotate it on the right angle until you get what you want

Comment: @merlin sorry it looks like I provided the incorrect link for a sample. here is the correct link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2orfvqtbibjmgt3/blackHole.blend?dl=0

Comment: @tiCreativeMedia Please edit your question instead of posting links as coments,  also it would be preferential if you used the [blend-exchange upload facility](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)